# Access public Laravel API only from certain server IP?

Tags: laravel, api

I have an existing Laravel application. Now, I want to create another application with Laravel, using the same database as the first app, but to be on its own server.

The API route would be like:

```
Route::apiResource('posts', PostsController::class)->only(['index', 'show']);
```

Is it possible to secure this route and access it only from the IP of the new application server?

Comment: Best way will be to implement api auth with the Laravel Sanctum or Passport packages. You'll probably want to check out Sanctum https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum. Example of protecting routes: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#protecting-routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a middleware and use it in your route.

First create it:

```
php artisan make:middleware IpMiddleware
```

Code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IpMiddleware
{
    
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->ip() != "192.168.0.155") {
        // here instead of checking a single ip address we can do collection of ips
        //address in constant file and check with in_array function
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Then add the new middleware class in the $`middleware` property of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //....
    'ipcheck' => \App\Http\Middleware\IpMiddleware::class,
];
```

Then set the middelware on your route:

```
Route::apiResource('posts', ['middleware' => ['ipcheck'], function () {
// your routes here
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few available packages that provide the tools to do this for you. I've not tried any myself so I can't vouch for their quality:

https://github.com/antonioribeiro/firewall

or

https://github.com/orkhanahmadov/laravel-ip-middleware/blob/master/src/Middleware.php

I think they both achieve the primary goal by providing a Middleware that checks the IP address of the incoming request and prevents the request if address doesn't match any listed IPs.

The code, in its simplest form would be something along the lines of:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (in_array($request->ip(), config('ip_whitelist'))) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    abort(403);
}
```

Where `config('ip_whitelist')` returns an array of IP addresses.

I assume you would pair this with the usual API auth such as Sanctum